# pg_locks table has lot of simple select statements

Tags: postgresql, locking, database-connection, database-locking

we are connecting to our Postgresql (RDS) server from our django backend as well as lambda, sometimes django backend queries time out and I run the following query to see the locks:

```
                SELECT
                    pg_stat_activity.client_addr,
                    pg_stat_activity.query
                FROM pg_class
                JOIN
                    pg_locks ON pg_locks.relation = pg_class.oid
                JOIN
                    pg_stat_activity ON pg_locks.pid =
                    pg_stat_activity.pid
                WHERE
                    pg_locks.granted='t' AND
                    pg_class.relname='accounts_user'
```

This gives me 30 rows of simple select queries executed from lambda like this:

```
SELECT first_name, picture, username FROM accounts_user WHERE id = $1
```

why does this query hold a lock? should I be worried?

I'm using pg8000 library to connect from Lambda

```
    with pgsql.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            """
            SELECT first_name, picture, username
            FROM accounts_user
            WHERE id = %s
            """,
            (author_user_id,),
        )
        row = cursor.fetchone()
    # use the row ..
```

I opened an issue at Github maybe it's because I'm using the library wrong. https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000/issues/16

Comment: Please show the locks that are being held.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe should I make SELECT * in the first query and paste the output?

Comment: Either that, or the complete `pg_locks` (if it is not too large).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you very much, I will definitely update, I'm not the DBA so don't have access so it will take some time!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to reuse the database connection, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#conn-max-age

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            ...
            'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600,             # reuse database connection
        }
    }
```